# c# inject text in to to fields in html page

Tags: javascript, c#, httprequest, html-agility-pack, webscarab

Maybe its just me being a little dumb but I can't find a way to input text into the fields on a website using C#, I have tried looking at HTML agility pack and some javascript injection, but can't find a simple or smart way to do this. Let me come with an example.

Here a html snip from a online website:

```
<fieldset>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Vejnavn, husnummer, postnummer" id="autocomplete-adgangsadresse2" class="span3 ui-autocomplete-input">
</fieldset>
```

I would like to inject some text in so the field to make a automatic seach for me.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: And how are you rendering this html? Or is this the html from another website? In which case, how did you get this html?

Comment: if i use html agility:

var url = "Website";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);

Comment: And why would you want to edit the value in that string? I am sensing an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using HTMLAgilityPack:

```
var doc = web.Load(url);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@id='autocomplete-adga‌​ngsadresse2']").Firs‌​t(); 
if (node != null) { 
    node.SetAttributeValue("value", "new value"); 
}
```